# What should be done if the accepted answer is factually less true than another answer?

Tags: discussion

Another question of a similar but not identical nature for reference: [What should happen when a new answer is more accurate than the existing acctepted answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/what-should-happen-when-a-new-answer-is-more-accurate-than-the-existing-acctepte) (hereby known as Question 1)

With reference to [Why do the training drone's shots not bounce off the lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110851/why-do-the-training-drones-shots-not-bounce-off-the-lightsaber/) (hereby known as Question 2)

Question 1 asks what should be done when a different answer is more accurate than the accepted answer. In that context, the accepted answer WAS correct but the years passed, people changed, new decisions were made, and so more recent events become more correct than the accepted answer.

Question 2 is a different context. The question asks for in-universe facts. The accepted answer appears to be correct, until you see the unaccepted answer. If you know your lore well enough you will know it is wrong. A training drone's shots are made of plasma, not electricity. When you compare the accepted answerer's reasoning in the comments to the sources quoted in the unaccepted answer, you'll realised the answerer made an incorrect observation, leading to an incorrect conclusion about the nature of training bolts. If you get the nature of the bolts wrong, your answer for why the shots don't deflect off the lightsaber cannot be correct, because the physics for plasma and electricity is completely different. Therefore the accepted answer is factually wrong.

Generalising from this particular instance, what should be done if there is an unaccepted answer for some given question which, is more accurate than the accepted answer based on the facts, or if the accepted answer is completely wrong? It can be based on common knowledge or sense, or known information from within the story universe. I feel that sometimes, some askers accept the first answer to come along that seems to make sense, without making sure the answer is logically sound and/or actually correct (when I was in school, I was taught a good answer should be in a point-elaboration-evidence-conclusion format).

As an example, here's one such scenario (not real):

> Question: Did Anakin kill younglings during Order 66?
>
> Accepted answer: Kanan was a youngling during Order 66, and he's still alive in Rebels, so no.
>
> Another answer: Yes. The official novelisation of the movie said so. *quotes the book*

The answer to Question 1 says more accurate answers should indeed be made an answer. But what if the asker doesn't come back to change it? Are we to leave it as it is? That doesn't seem right, it runs contrary to the intent of questions and answers to serve the community instead of just the asker.

Other suggestions in the comments say:

> "In general, this is why there's voting as well - the later answer should get higher votes and so appear right next to the accepted answer."
>
> "In the case that the asker is no longer around, at least the better answer may eventually be rewarded the Populist badge."

I don't feel those are good ideas. That green tick is meant to be a universally recognisable visual cue for the correct answer. It exists so that people with the same question can find the correct answer without greater scrutiny. Why should we be confusing them by saying "the one with more votes is more correct, not the one that is accepted and has a green tick"? Awarding the more correct, better voted but unaccepted answer with a badge awards an answerer for submitting it, but doesn't contribute to the question serving the community correctly.

**What can be done when an accepted answer is wrong based on facts and another answer is correct/more correct? Do higher rep members have the ability to change which answer is accepted, or if that's not possible then what else can be done?**

Apologies in advance if I missed out anything I wanted to say or if anything else seem off. It's 4am here =D

Comment: Basically, there's not much we can do other than leaving a comment and voting as appropriate. Only the OP can change acceptance, and if they're not interested in doing so then our hands are tied

Comment: Also http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/, though I don't think I agree with Himarm's idea

Comment: The green tick may often be seen as "this is the right answer", but technically it denotes the answer that either solved the problem or was the most useful.

Comment: so, basically... everyone should upvote [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110851/why-do-the-training-drones-shots-not-bounce-off-the-lightsaber/110852#110852) since it has a source that disproves the (currently) accepted answer :)

Comment: @phantom42 even so, I don't think the accepted answer in this case fits the technical definition. I think we have a loophole for when the asker doesn't use the accept answer feature correctly...

Comment: using the feature correctly is marking whatever satisfies the OP at the time. you don't get to decide what makes them happy.